# Selenium Select object not firing Ajax Call

Tags: java, ajax, selenium

I've 2 Select objects, after a value the first one is selected, the second one trigger an ajax call and update its values. This behavior seems not to work using selenium with the following code:

```
driver.get("MyURL");
WebElement regionElement = driver.findElement(By.id("FirstID"));
Select dropDownRegion = new Select(regionElement);
dropDownRegion.selectByValue("myValue");
WebElement provinceElement = driver.findElement(By.id("DDLProvince"));
Select dropDownProvince = new Select(provinceElement);
for(WebElement optionProvince :dropDownProvince.getOptions()) {
    System.out.println("*****************Province: " + optionProvince.getText() + " *************");
}
```

The result of the print always the default option/value ("Please select a Province" in my case).

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to create a wait until the element is there. The ajax call will most probably be triggered, but your code does not wait for it to result

Answer (score 0):

> I've 2 Select objects, after a value the first one is selected, the second one trigger an ajax call and update its values.

In this case you should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until `<select>` has options as below :-

```
Select dropDownRegion = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("FirstID")););
dropDownRegion.selectByValue("myValue");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

//Now wait for nested options for this select element 
List<WebElement> optionProvinces = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfNestedElementsLocatedBy(By.id("DDLProvince"), By.tagName("option")));

for(WebElement optionProvince : optionProvinces) {
        System.out.println("*****************Province: " + optionProvince.getText() + " *************");
}
```

**Edited**:- As you know above code will wait until options present in the select box but if it would found an option as default option which is already present then this would become true an you would still not found actual options.

In this case you should try using `numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan` to wait until element present more than given number as below :-

```
List<WebElement> optionProvinces = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(By.cssSelector("select#DDLProvince option"), 2));

for(WebElement optionProvince : optionProvinces) {
        System.out.println("*****************Province: " + optionProvince.getText() + " *************");
}
```

Or you can also wait until ajax call complete before finding second dropdown as below :-

```
Select dropDownRegion = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("FirstID")););
dropDownRegion.selectByValue("myValue");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

//Now wait until ajax call complete 
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
  public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
      return (Boolean)js.executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0");
}};

//Now find the second dropdown 
Select dropDownProvince = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("DDLProvince")););
for(WebElement optionProvince : dropDownProvince.getOptions()) {
  System.out.println("*****************Province: " + optionProvince.getText() + " *************");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Saurabh. even with this changes, the select didn't get updated. it shows only the default element (Pleae select ....)

Comment: Ah, then you should try using `numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan` to wait until element present more than given number. Try with edited answer and let me know

Comment: Or you can also try to wait until ajax call complete..see updated answer..:)